# LINQ and C# summary

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a relational table which has parent child rows. Some of the rows have a `typeId` and I would like to get a summary of the total cost by the type:

[image]

The list on the left is some sample data and the list on the right is the summary result expected.

The data is in a datatable. Can anyone help me with this.

**ie:**

- `typeId = 1`: Which would be calculated by: *30 (total cost of 3,2) x 5 (qty of 2,1) x 3 (qty of 1,null)*

(30 x 5 x 3) = 450

- `typeId = 2`: Which would be calculated by: *12 (total cost of 5,1) x 3 (qty of 1,null)
  x 15 (total cost 4,2)  x 5 (qty of 2,1) x 3 (qty of 1,null)*

(12 x 3) + (15 x 5 x 3) = 261

Here is some sample code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable( "Summary" );

dt.Columns.Add( "Id", Type.GetType( "System.Int32" ) );
dt.Columns.Add( "ParentId", Type.GetType( "System.Int32" ) );
dt.Columns.Add( "Qty", Type.GetType( "System.Int32" ) );
dt.Columns.Add( "Cost", Type.GetType( "System.Decimal" ) );
dt.Columns.Add( "TotalCost", Type.GetType( "System.Decimal" ) );
dt.Columns.Add( "TypeId", Type.GetType( "System.Int32" ) );

dt.Rows.Clear();

DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["Id"] = 1;
row["ParentId"] = DBNull.Value;
row["Qty"] = 3;
row["Cost"] = 237.00;
row["TotalCost"] = 711.00;
row["TypeId"] = DBNull.Value;
dt.Rows.Add( row );

row = dt.NewRow();
row["Id"] = 2;
row["ParentId"] = 1;
row["Qty"] = 5;
row["Cost"] = 45.00;
row["TotalCost"] = 225.00;
row["TypeId"] = DBNull.Value;
dt.Rows.Add( row );

row = dt.NewRow();
row["Id"] = 3;
row["ParentId"] = 2;
row["Qty"] = 30;
row["Cost"] = 1.00;
row["TotalCost"] = 30.00;
row["TypeId"] = 1;
dt.Rows.Add( row );

row = dt.NewRow();
row["Id"] = 4;
row["ParentId"] = 2;
row["Qty"] = 1;
row["Cost"] = 15.00;
row["TotalCost"] = 15.00;
row["TypeId"] = 2;
dt.Rows.Add( row );

row = dt.NewRow();
row["Id"] = 5;
row["ParentId"] = 1;
row["Qty"] = 4;
row["Cost"] = 3.00;
row["TotalCost"] = 12.00;
row["TypeId"] = 2;
dt.Rows.Add( row );
```

Comment: No- I just dummied up some for the images I have code to generate the datatable

Comment: total cost of 3,2 is 255 why you said 30?

Comment: @Saeed Because it's the sum of the cost of 3 and his ParentId 2. So 30 in the DataTable is the TotalCost.

Comment: I can't see this in your data table, 3's cost is 1, 2's cost is 45, 3's total cost is 30, 2's total cost is 225, how you found 30 as total cost of 2 and 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need a recursive routine which is not something I would try in pure Linq, so I would try something like this.

```
var summary =  
    (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where r["TypeID"] != DBNull.Value  
    group r by (int) r["TypeId"] into results
    select new 
        { 
        results.Key , 
        TotalCost = results.Sum(r=> (decimal) r["TotalCost"] *  GetParentsQty(r) )
        }
    );


public int GetParentsQty(DataRow child )
{
    if (child["ParentID"] == DBNull.Value)
        return 1;

    var parent = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                  where (int) child["ParentID"] == (int) row["Id"] 
                  select row
                 ).Single();

    return (int) parent ["Qty"]  * GetParentsQty(parent);
}
```